# Concatenating Title and Name Strings in Access

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2016

I'm trying to concatenate the title, first name, and last name of a contact into one string in an Access report. Currently I am using a text field with the control set to

```
=[ContactTitle] & ' ' & [FirstName] & ' ' & [LastName]
```

However, some contacts don't have a title associated with them and my method leaves a leading space which makes the text alignment on my report look sloppy. So I'm wondering, is there a way to concatenate but only include that first space if the contact title is not null? I am aware of the plus operator but not experienced enough to see a way to use it in this case without just making my entire string null.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `+` operator for concatenation.

Concatenating with `+` yields `Null` if any of the values you're concatenating are `Null`:

```
=([ContactTitle] + " ") & ([FirstName] + " ") & [LastName]
```

Do note that some devs frown upon using `+` for concatenation, stating that `&` is *the* concatenation operator in VBA.

Also note that if one of the parameters is a zero-length string, this won't work. Only a real Null will lead to the result being Null.

Comment: The question says that it's the `[ContactTitle]` field that may be null, not the other two.

Comment: @Taazar True, I'm checking for the other field too to illustrate how to use this concatenation technique. The parentheses are the only added characters and it has no real relevance for execution time.

Comment: Ah right, sorry I thought you may have just misread the question.

Comment: This is neat, i never knew you could do that, +1

Answer (score 4):

You could use the `IIf()` method to check if the title is null and then depending on the answer insert or don't insert a space.

You can also use the `Nz()` method to check for zero-length strings at the same time as null strings by setting all null values to be a zero-length string and then comparing the result to `""`.

The code I would recommend you use here is:

```
=IIf(Nz([ContactTitle],"") = "", "", [ContactTitle] & " ") & [FirstName] & " " & [LastName]
```

If you you have any problems with this or need a better explaination leave a comment and I'll get back to you.